# How to use Same style as Bootstrap 2.3.2 in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

To me, Bootstrap 3 doesn't look very nice and I find the bootstrap  2.3.2 much nicer! Now my question is is there any way to use new functions and style added to bootstrap3 but still use the same style? I already ried to customize Bootstrap based on Bootstrap  2.3.2 but I couldn't figure out how to define some of the changes. For example: in Bootstrap3 the `@line-height-base` is 1.428571429 and this parameter in Bootstrap 2.3.2 is `@baseLineHeight: 20px`

**Update:**
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you simply use 2.3.2?

Comment: does this style look like bootstrap 2 (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/) ?

Comment: @ hi Ken , if you take a look at attache-updated image I compared both navbar in previous version and the link that sent here.As you can see the height of navbars are different and this is almost happening in some other components like  Alert.

Comment: @Ken: that example uses v3.

Comment: @RoyMJ because Bootstrap 3 is more optimized for mobiles and so is faster

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 3 now comes with a `bootstrap-theme.css` file that includes the bootstrap 2.3.2 styling (for the most part).

Simply add this file into your project after the base `boostrap.css` file.

Comment: Hi Schmalzy, Thanks for your comment but as you can see from the link that Ken provided above, there is the bootstrap-theme.css hooked after bootstrap.css but it is still following Bootstrap3 styles!

Comment: Its not perfect, but its pretty close to 2.3.2. Anything else that is missing, you would just need to use the customize page in the docs. or add your own custom CSS. But the `bootstrap-theme.css` file should get you 90% there. If you are not seeing ANY 2.3.2 styles, then there is something wrong with your code...

Comment: It's pity that Bootstrap 2.3.x looks more beautiful than Bootstrap 3.x.x with theme.